# Spring mvc compiled correctly but giving me 404 error when deploying on server

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, servlets, controller

I am a beginner with spring mvc and created my own application following some online tutorials. I followed an online tutorial to use jackson mapper in a java application,and it worked. Then I further tried to modify it and changed it to a spring mvc project,such that it sends the json data when the user calls the url from the web.

It works correctly if i run the application via tomcat server integrated with eclipse. However ,when I manualy copy/paste the war file into tomcat/webapps folder and start tomcat from bin/tomcat7.exe, it gives me a 404 error. Why does it give me a 404 error and how can I fix that?

please tell me what I might be doing wrong here,that will greatly help me learn more about spring mvc,thank you.

PS: I know there are similar questions here on stackoverflow regarding this,I tried following them to solve this issue but was unsuccessful

Here is my code :

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>  

</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

       JsonDemo jsonDemo = new JsonDemo();
       return jsonDemo.objectToJson();

   }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>HelloWorld</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloworldProject</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>HelloworldProject</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: what is the name of your war and how do you call your page?

Comment: which server you are trying to deploy it?

Comment: @NikolayRusev I am trying to deploy it in tomcat7

Comment: @Jens The name of the war file is HelloworldProject, I just added the pom.xml as well for reference.

Comment: @learner211 and which URL do you call?

Comment: @Jens after compilation it creates HelloworldProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war,so i removed the extra words and changed it just helloworld.war  , then i called localhost:8080/helloworld/hello

Comment: @learner211 Try localhost:8080/HelloworldProject/hello

Comment: by default Tomcat gives as root context the .war name which in your case is :
HelloworldProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. the app should be accessed with the url: http://localhost:8080/HelloworldProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello. see if will work

Comment: @learner211 Have you checked catalina logs? It should present some lines that tell you if your service was deployed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to mention severals problems you've got in your project:

1)  Please use this one: https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd.

It's ok to use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />` and `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` but you're using Spring 4.2.0 but your config file is using old 3.0 xsd.

To help you to deal with Spring config I'll post it here:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

2) I strongly advice you to migrate to servlet 3.0/3.1. Basically it means changing your web.xml header:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
 <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

Please note some important changes:

- insted of giving an init-param we are using context-param for your Spring Servlet.
- listener which creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters

3) Add some other dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
   <!-- Spring dependencies -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This would help you to deal with mvc.

If you could test all of these and provide a full catalina log including the deployment this would greatly help for resolving the issue.

4) Controller class:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@RestController
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

       JsonDemo jsonDemo = new JsonDemo();
       return jsonDemo.objectToJson();

   }

}
```

Comment: I followed what you said,now I am seeing actual errors. When i run the url from controller, the output is being displayed in the console,but not on the web browser. I have added the log in the question,and it shows the output after calling  the url.

Comment: Please find the code attached in my answer. You should annotate your controller as JsonController.